# ListView does not display properly when list items are less

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to make an app where in I make use of list view, I see a strange issue, wherein if the number of items in my listview are less than it does not populate properly. 
However as soon as I have more elements in the list view it populates correctly.
I am attaching two screenshots which should explain the problem. Please do help me here.

[image: List view appearing properly]

[image: See the white space when i have just 2 elements to show]

My Adapter code is as below:-

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if(layoutInflater == null){
        layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    if (convertView == null){
        convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.describing_dish_list,null);
    }

    if (dishImageLoader == null){
        dishImageLoader=AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    }

    Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG,"DishListAdapter SET DISH NAME");
    TextView dishName=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dish_name);
    TextView dishExplore=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dish_explore);
    FeedImageView dishImageView =(FeedImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_dish_pic);

    DishDetails dishDetails= dishDetailsList.get(position);
    dishName.setText(dishDetails.getDish_name());
    //Fetching Dish Image
    if(dishDetails.getDish_picture() != null) {

        dishImageView.setImageUrl(dishDetails.getDish_picture(), dishImageLoader);
        dishImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dishImageView.setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver(){

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG,"The IMG URL met an error");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.d(OrderUpdateConfig.TAG,"The IMG URL was loaded successfully ");
            }
        });
    }else{
        dishImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    return convertView;
}
```

Layout files are as under:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="@null"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Layout file of the list elements :-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/input_login_hint"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_dish_explore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="13dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_dish_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"/>

        <com.example.saunakc.utils.FeedImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_dish_pic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: less than what?  if there are not enough elements to fill up the screen, what do you expect to have displayed?

Comment: Also, post your adapter code.

Comment: By complete view .. I mean that atleast the picture that is there should display properly ..

Comment: Adapter code added

Comment: ok.  please post layout file as well.  layout for the listview and also layout for the listview items.

Comment: Added the files here.

Comment: ok, I don't know for sure if this will solve your problem, but I see that your listview line item layout file has one LinearLayout nested inside of the other, and both have the same orientation.  That is redundant.  Combine the attributes from your two LinearLayouts into a single LinearLayout element.  Having redundant nested layouts may be creating some unexpected behavior.  If it works, let me know and I'll post that as an answer.

Comment: That does not make a difference I tried that

Comment: ok.  can you post what the image in your example is -supposed- to look like?  I'd like to see if the image is getting cropped, scaled, or what.  Also, does this happen only when you have exactly one item in your listview, or anytime the content in the listview is too small to fill up the screen?

Comment: As i keep increasing the elements of the list view the problem of displaying those also and the element also loads up correctly.

Comment: I don't understand your most recent comment

Comment: If you look at both the images that i have posted above, in the first one we can see two full images out of a total of 10 images that I have , however in case of the second one I have a total of only 2 images, but those two are not being displayed properly.

Comment: your second image only shows one image, not two.  I think you may need to post some better examples.  And there is no way for me to know that you had 10 images in the first example.  You should post images that show "actual results" and "expected results" so that your question is clear.  otherwise we will just chase our tails for hours.

Comment: And thats where my list view comes into affect , if i scroll through the other images will come across..